# Invalid Date Issue but Date is Invalid

Tags: javascript, date, datatable

I have a date format

> 03.03.2016 20:01

And I have a code

```
aData._date = new Date(aData[3]).getTime();
```

error is that date is invalid but, at different computer it worked well but now it is not working .What is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because on your different computer, you're using Firefox. And right now you're using chrome. Only chrome who can parse ambiguous date format string like that into date object.

Comment: How can I run this on both chrome and firefox ?

Comment: You can use `moment.js` easily. Or parse the date string to be ISO8601 format first

Comment: Thanks solved with parsing :)   aData._date = new Date(Date.parse(aData[3])).getTime();

Comment: Really? when creating `new Date` it should have called `Date.parse` method. That couldn't be the solution :(

Comment: @Çağrı—converting from one prolematic format to a slightly less problematic format doesn't really solve the issue though while you continue to use the Date constructor to parse it.

Comment: @choz—I think the OP means parse it to generate an ISO 8601 format string.

Comment: @Çağrı—`new Date(Date.parse(aData[3]))` is exactly equivalent to `new Date(aData[3])` per [*ECMA-262 §20.3.2.2 3.b.ii*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the problem?

Parsing of strings using the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is largely implementation dependent and is not recommended. Manually parse strings, either with a small function if you only have to deal with a single format, or use a library (there are many good ones to choose from) and provide the format otherwise.

ECMAScript 2015 specifies that *Date.parse* correctly parse ISO 8601 extended format dates, however any other format is implementation dependent. Many browsers in use do not correctly (i.e. per the specification) parse ISO 8601 format dates either.

"03.03.2016 20:01" is not an ISO 8601 date format. Assuming it's DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm it can be parsed as a local date and time using:

```js
function parseDMYHM(s){
  var b = ('' || s).split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], b[1]-1, b[0], b[3], b[4]);
}

document.write(parseDMYHM('03.03.2016 20:01'));
```

Or if you have a library with a *parse* function that accepts a format to parse (as such libraries that are any good will), using something like:

```
var d = parse('03.03.2016 20:01', 'DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm');
```

Comment: Nice approach.. I'd suggest the OP goes for the 2nd one which is to create its own `parse` method..

Answer (score 1):

You can first parse your date string to [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
'03.03.2016 20:01' to '2016-03-03T20:01:00'
```

When you pass the date string to `Date` constructor, it calls [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) methods. And it only accepts in a version of ISO8601. But somehow, chrome has their extended feature to parse date-like string into `Date.parse` method.

This is one way to achieve what you want if you don't want to use external library.

```
var dateStr = aData[3]; // 03.03.2016 20:01
var matches = dateStr.match(/[0-9]+/g);
var year = matches[2];
var month = matches[1];
var day = matches[0];
var hour = matches[3];
var minute = matches[4];

var formattedDateStr = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + hour + ':' + minute;
aData._date = new Date(formattedDateStr).getTime();
```

Comment: Seems to me if you're going to the bother of parsing the string, you should pass the values directly to the Date constructor and not go back to the vagaries of using it to parse another string.

Comment: @RobG Haha.. I failed to notice which is `month` or `day`.. So I'd figure to  create them in case the OP wants to switch between em.. :)

Comment: I think you missed my point. Instead of creating a new string and using Date to parse it, provide the values directly: `new Date(year, month-1, day, hour, minute)` which is compatible and completely reliable in every implementation of ECMAScript that is likely to be in use now or ever into the future.