# Date Format Wrong from datatable

Tags: javascript, date, datatable, date-range

I have a problem about date format from datatable

> 07.01.2016 17:35

if for mat comes like that  it reads day as month and month as day but if comes

> 14.01.2016 17:35

it reads true I am trying to make date range but , wrong date comes from table how can i fix it ?
Thanks is advance.

```
var minDateFilter;
                         var maxDateFilter;




                         $('#datepicker_from').click(function () {
                             $("#datepicker_from").datepicker("show");
                         });
                         $('#datepicker_to').click(function () {
                             $("#datepicker_to").datepicker("show");
                         });
                         $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
                             "onSelect": function (date) {
                                 minDateFilter = new Date(Date.parse(date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd")).getTime();
                                 //alert(Date.parse(date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
                                 oTable.draw();
                                 //alert(Date.parse(date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
                             }
                         }).keyup(function () {
                             minDateFilter = new Date(Date.parse(this.value).toString("yyyy/MM/dd")).getTime();

                             oTable.draw();
                         });

                         $("#datepicker_to").datepicker({
                             "onSelect": function (date) {
                                 maxDateFilter = new Date(Date.parse(date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd")).getTime();
                                 oTable.draw();
                             }
                         }).keyup(function () {
                             maxDateFilter = new Date(Date.parse(this.value).toString("yyyy/MM/dd")).getTime();
                             oTable.draw();
                         });
                         $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
                         function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {

                             if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
                                 aData._date = new Date(Date.parse(aData[3]).toString("yyyy/MM/dd")).getTime();
                                 //alert(Date.parse(aData[3]).toString("yyyy/MM/dd"));

                             }

                             if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
                                 //alert(aData._date + "<" + minDateFilter);
                                 if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {

                                     return false;
                                 }
                             }

                             if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
                                 if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
                                     return false;
                                 }
                             }

                             return true;
                         }
                       );
```

Comment: Using the Date constructor to parse a date in the format `07.01.2016 17:35` is entirely implementation dependent, it should not be relied on at all.  `new Date(Date.parse(date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd")).getTime()` is nonsensical. *Date.parse* returns a number, its *toString* method does not take arguments so that is ignored. `new Date(Date.parse(value))` where *value* is a string is identical to `new Date(value)`. Neither the *Date* constructor nor *Date.parse* take a format as a second argument (though kudos for recognising that it's a good idea to provide one). ;-)

Comment: Didn't the answers to your question [*Invalid Date Issue but Date is Invalid*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782707/invalid-date-issue-but-date-is-invalid) fix this issue?